# Send image data from an html tag using AJAX to PHP and save it in MySQL as blob data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to send the image data from the html img tag using AJAX and save it in my MySQL db. I have a column in my db which is a longblob datatype, thats where I'm going to store the image. I also have other data that I'm going to save along with it but my main concern is the image, I don't know how to do it. I did try to find answers here on and other sites but didn't find what I was looking for. My code looks like this.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        <label>ARP No.</label>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="arp-no" class="form-control" id='arp-no' required=""/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        <label>Owner</label>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="owner" id="owner" class="form-control" value="" required=""/>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is where the image tag is

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <img name="map-sketch" id="image" width="100%" height="100%" src='http://www.thekrausemouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Sample.jpg'></img>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveFaas()">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2" id="saving-info"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript AJAX:

```
function saveFaas(){
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this information?')) {
    var params = 'kind=land';
    params += '&arp-no='+document.getElementById('arp-no').value;
    params += '&owner='+document.getElementById('owner').value;

    //the image data
    params += '&image=';

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("saving-info").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }else { // waiting for result 
            document.getElementById('saving-info').innerHTML = '<img src="../images/ajax_loader.gif">';
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "../functions/save-faas.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}}
```

Can I pass the image data like the others?

Php:

```
<?php
//db info
include('../fragments/db-config.php');

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$kind = $_POST['kind'];
if ($kind == 'land') {
    $image = $_POST['image']; // the image

    $arp_no = $_POST['arp-no'];
    $owner = $_POST['owner'];

    $sql = "UPDATE faas SET arp_number='$arp_no', owner_name='$owner' 
    WHERE faas_id=$faas_id;";
}


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<label>Record Updated</label>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close();   ?>
```

So to wrap it up. I have an image data in my html, call ajax to send the image and the other data in php and save it in mysql db.

My javascript code here is in plain javascript so I would like a plain javascript solution also. Thank you.

Comment: Well, something to consider is that the image appears to be an offsite resource. If this is the case, you can't reliably suck it off the web with an AJAX request - think of the CORS problem. What _I'd_ do is send the address of the image to the your back-end as part of your ajax payload. Then, in your php code, you can get the image with a `file_get_contents` call, before saving the result to your database. That said, it's often better to give the file a random name, save to the backend's filesystem and then store the relevant details to your database - there's less I/O overhead.

Comment: @enhzflep the image that I put is just a sample, actually the image that will be put and be save is an image from the clipboard, its a copy and paste image from a third party software. Regarding your answer, can I send the image address like this:

var image = document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("src");

//then pass the variable image to the params like this:
params += '&image='+image;

is that correct?

Now on the server-side i don't know how to do it can you write a sample code. Thank you.

Comment: That changes things considerably. How do you imagine you'll communicate the contents of the clipboard with the web-page? And yes - the idea you have for grabbing the `.src` attribute and appending it to the `GET` parameters is what I had in mind (or a `POST` version - either are fine, though you'll need to `url_encode` the src before appending it if you use `GET`). Make a new php file and try using `file_get_contents` with a hard-coded url, before using `fopen` and `fwrite` then `fclose` to save the result of this call to disk. It's easy and you'll benefit from doing the work yourself. :)